# Properly package JS code without having to worry about "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have some JS code, and want to package it so that it is easy to use.
I had this:

```
var myID = {
windowref : undefined,
intervalID : null,
 checkLogin : function(){
    if (this.windowref==undefined){
        console.log(windowref)
        console.log("no ref yet")
        return false;
    }
    if (this.windowref.closed){
        console.log("window closed")
        clearInterval(this.intervalID)
        this.intervalID=null
    }
    if (this.windowref.location.href=='mycallbackurl'){
        console.log("login detected")
        clearInterval(this.intervalID)
        this.intervalID=null
        this.windowref.close()
    }
},
login_process: function(){
    this.windowref = window.open('oneURL',
        "login with MY ID","width=600, height=400")
    console.log(self)
    if (this.windowref!=null){
        this.intervalID =  setInterval(this.checkLogin,500)
    }
}
}
```

when I tried to use it like so :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a#login_push').on("click",myID.login_process.bind(myID)); 
});
```

I got issues with 'this' not being in the proper scope ( was scoped to the element returned by jquery.
I changed it to :

```
var myID = {
    windowref : undefined,
    intervalID : null,
     checkLogin : function(){
        if (this.windowref==undefined){
            return false;
        }
        if (this.windowref.closed){
            console.log("window closed")
            clearInterval(this.intervalID)
            this.intervalID=null
        }
        if (this.windowref.location.href=='mycallbackurl'){
            console.log("login detected")
            clearInterval(this.intervalID)
            this.intervalID=null
            this.windowref.close()
        }
    },
    login_process: function(){
        this.windowref = window.open('myloginurl',
            "login with my ID","width=600, height=400")
        if (this.windowref!=null){
            this.intervalID =  setInterval(this.checkLogin.bind(myID),500)
        }
    }
}
```

this works if I also bind when setting the event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a#login_push').on("click",myID.login_process.bind(myID)); 
});
```

Is there a "proper" way to write this so that I could package this in a sort of "SDK" and the developers would only need to do something of the sort:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $('a#login_push').on("click",myID.login_process); 
    });
```

I tried setting self to this in the object literal, and then using self instead of this, but it did not work.

Comment: you could always just use the object identifier instead of `this` - `if (myID.windowref==undefined){`

Comment: thank you! this is a great way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you could use `myID` instead of `this`. Another way is to export a bound version of the function:

```
myID.login_process = function () {
    // ...
}.bind(myID);
```